# Scrapy Pagination not working after a few days

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to webscraping with python and scrapy and wrote my first spider last weekend (see code below).

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class MobileSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mobile'
    start_urls = ['https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?dam=0&isSearchRequest=true&ms=17500%3B49%3B%3B&pageNumber=1&ref=quickSearch&sb=rel&vc=Car']
    page_number = 1

    def parse(self, response):

        # stop spider when no quotes found in response
        if len(response.css('div.mN_WC.qEvrY')) == 0:
            raise CloseSpider('No quotes in response')

        for products in response.css('div.mN_WC.qEvrY'):
            yield {
                'name': products.css('h2.QeGRL::text').get(),
                'price': products.css('span.fpviJ::text').get().replace('\xa0€',''),
                'info': products.css('div.HaBLt').get(),
                'link': products.css('a.rqEvz.FWtU1.YIC4W').attrib['href'],

            }
        # Go to next page
        self.page_number += 1
        next_page = f'https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/search.html?dam=0&isSearchRequest=true&ms=17500%3B49%3B%3B&pageNumber={self.page_number}&ref=quickSearch&sb=rel&vc=Car'
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Last week, the spider was running as expected and scraped all pages. Surprisingly, when I ran the spider today it only returned content for the first page. After switching to page 2 the response appeared to be empty because my stop condition became true. However, when I scrape the second page manually via the scrapy shell it works fine.

Any ideas what could be the problem here? Any hints would be highly appreciated!

Comment: portals from time to time may change HTML code - ie. to make it more modern, nicer, safer, use javascript to load it faster, etc. - and first you should check if portal has exactly the same HTML.

Comment: some portals may have complex system to stop hackers, spamers and scrapers. Maybe portal block access for your scraper or it sends page with `Captcha` to check if you are real human. Maybe first check `response.page_source` to see what you get in HTML. Maybe there will be some usefull information.

Comment: thanks for the hints. Indeed I was sent a captcha by the website after the first page. I could resolve this now via proxy rotation. However, I am still surprised, that the spider ran successfully through 50+ pages when I executed it for this first time. Would be interesting to understand how these detection systems operate.

Comment: different pages may different methods for this. Basic method is to check header `User-Agent` because tools like `requests` send `python/requests` instead of ` Mozilla/5.0 ...`. But `Scrapy` should have option or extension to change randomly `User-Agent`. Server may also check `IP` and time between requests. Human can't open 100 pages in 1 second. They may also check if client can use `JavaScript` because real browser mostly have active `JavaScript` but `requests` or `scrapy` can't run `JavaScript` - and it may need to use `Selenium` and `scrapy-selenium` (or `Splash`)